# How to send "no-reply" email to users?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, email

I have a spring MVC application where I want to send a **no-reply email** after each user registration.
To send a **no-reply email**, what all configuration needs to do in service providers like Gmail or anything, we need to write extra code in java.

or is there any 3rd party tool available which handles this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no magic for this.  A "no reply" email is one which has a Reply-to: address that goes to a mailbox that will be ignored or discarded.  Usually you use a mailbox name that indicates to the user that their reply will be ignored.

For example:

```
Reply-to: no-replies@example.com    # assuming 'example.com' is your domain.
```

Typically you don't want replies to the "no reply" email to bounce.  But that is an option too.

> To send a no-reply email , what all configuration need to do in service provider like gmail or anything we need to write extra code in java.

No configuration is needed.  You just code the mail sender (e.g. your Java application) to include a "Reply-to:" header.

However, you will need to set up the mail server that hosts the "no reply" mailbox so the the emails are discarded.

Note: it would be a bad idea to use a 3rd-parties email domain (real or fake) for your "no reply" email address.  Why?  Because some people reply to the "no reply" address anyway.  If the domain is owned  by someone else, there is nothing to stop them from setting up a mail server to capture the emails ... and harvest confidential information.